# Automated documentation for AutoIt

Tags: javadoc, doxygen, autoit

Is there an automated documentation tool like Javadoc or Doxygen for AutoIt?  Or an AutoIt plugin for Doxygen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sortof. AutoIt UDFs use a header format which is converted to chm form using a several stage process which is not really designed for public usage but can be found [here](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/udfs/UDF_BuildTemplates.htm).

That is the official one. However, there are a number of user submitted variants on the forum such as [this](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/91203-standard-udf-function-comments-to-chm-help-files/) one which may be better suited to your needs.

As far as I am aware there is no plugin for Doxygen, and there is no plans for it either.

Comment: @RiponAlWasim I don't know when that was taken offline, but there is another reference on the wiki [here](https://www.autoitscript.com/wiki/UDF-spec) that as far as I'm aware has all the information on the original page as well as more guidelines and features of the conversion process.

Answer (score 0):

[Natural Docs](https://www.naturaldocs.org/) is an alternative to Doxygen that support AutoIT

You can refer to this project [[UDF] G-Engin](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/132103-udf-g-engin/) to check the syntax applied in AutoIT.